# Getting Error while sending json objects as headers in mule 4 http connector

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

my Https header is in this format in Mule http requester

```
%dw 2.0 
output application/java
{    "Content-Transfer-Encoding" :"base64",
    "X-do-Authentication" : {"Username": "xxx@yyy.org","Password": "xxxyyy","IntegratorKey": "4xzzzz"}
}
```

whem trying to send header in this format I am getting this error

```
Message               : "java.lang.IllegalStateException - No read or write handler for Username
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No read or write handler for Username
    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.pojo.reader.PropertyDefinition._type$lzycompute(PropertyDefinition.scala:44)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.pojo.reader.PropertyDefinition._type(PropertyDefinition.scala:35)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.pojo.reader.PropertyDefinition.classType(PropertyDefinition.scala:70)
```

I tried setting output to text/plain but this is still not working how can I proceed on this. I am using Mule 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to rewrite the object:
`{"Username": "xxx@yyy.org","Password": "xxxyyy","IntegratorKey": "4xzzzz"}`
to JSON by using:
`write({"Username": "xxx@yyy.org","Password": "xxxyyy","IntegratorKey": "4xzzzz"}, "application/json")`

Comment: Isn't it the same as already answered?

Comment: Sorry I didnt read your answer while posting this. And yet after read it I upvoted. And yet thanks for devoted.

Comment: Same as already answered. You could suggest an edit on the existing answer to add you code sample.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP Headers does not support JSON Object as a value. I think you need to pass the JSON String in the header. In other words you just need to convert JSON to String. You can use [`write`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-write) function for this

```
%dw 2.0 
output application/java
---
{    "Content-Transfer-Encoding" :"base64",
    "X-do-Authentication" : write({"Username": "xxx@yyy.org","Password": "xxxyyy","IntegratorKey": "4xzzzz"}, "application/json", {indent: false})
}
```